# python intercepting communication

Tags: python, networking, communication

lets say you run third party program on your computer whitch create a process named example.exe

how do i determinate if this process is running and how many windows does he open? How do i intercept network communication between this windows and server?

my goal is to create an app whitch will be monitoring network trafic between example.exe and its home server in order to analyze data and save to database, and finally simulate user interaction to get more relevant data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For network sniffing, use [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) to capture network traffic. [pypcap](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) is a Python interface to libpcap (WinPcap on Windows), which is used the popular network sniffer Wireshark (once known as Ethereal).

Regarding process information, such as whether it is running and finding all of its open windows, I'm pretty sure you can do this with the Windows API. This means that you can do it in Python using the [win32 library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) which lets you use most of the Windows API directly. So this now becomes a Windows API question, with which I can't help.

Please ask just one question per, umm, question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wireshark from wireshark.org to sniff the network traffic (or any other packet sniffer).